# How to ignore or copy a part of formula in EXCEL from one column to another?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

[image: Example image]

I have used formulas in the following way:

```
N9/SUM(K10:K11),
N12/SUM(K13:K22),
N23/SUM(K24:K32),
```

And so on...

I want to copy only `SUM(K10:K11)` this part of formula from each cell to another cell without changing the cell reference `K`.

How can I do it?

**Example:**

Cell `C4` uses formula `=A4/SUM(B5:B8)` now I need to copy only `SUM(B5:B8)` this part of formula to cell `D4`.

Comment: $K to anchor K during copying. You can use F4 to alternate between modes of anchors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to ignore 'N9', 'N12' and N23' parts of formulas while copying to new cells. How to do this? @Pagotti

Comment: I can't figure out. Can you put some example how you expect the result?

Comment: @Pagotti added example image link at the beginning of my question. and have explained the example too.

Comment: I think that you can't modify the formula being copying, but you can put a formula "=SUM($B5:$B8) in "D4" first and with a "=A4" in "C4" you can copy "D4" and "paste special" with "division" over C4 and Excel make "=A4/SUM($B5:$B8)" in C4 as result. (for this example, of course)

Comment: Ok thanks for the replies:) I will try this:) @Pagotti

Comment: I recommend you read the topic "how to ask a question" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get more answers from community because I think that is confuse and is a very specific problem.

Comment: Yes I will:) This was my first question. Sorry for the confusion:)

Answer (score 1):

**Advice relating to what you are attempting:**

As you are looking to have a part of the formula shown in another column I would have perhaps built that part of the formula in column D first, then referenced the result directly in column C: `=A4/D4`

You then have the desired result ready for you to copy down each column.

***This is vital to completing large formulas with vast amounts of data so I felt a clear description of the anchors would be best here. Feel free to comment this answer for more info.***

To completely emit a cell reference from your formula you will have to manually remove it or provide the logic in the formula for when it is not required (for example, only if there are no values above do the division of `A`).

Anchors are dollar signs used like so: `$A$1`

A Dollar sign used before the column will mean that the column will never change when you copy the formula across:

[image]

A Dollar sign used before the row number will mean that the row will never change when you copy the formula across:

[image]

And finally, with both dollar signs in the entire cell reference will not change when you copy formulas across:

[image]

Comment: @Shiv was this not what you were looking for?

Comment: So simple yet so brilliant! Thanks for sharing this tip about the dollar sign!